# Says I need an index for finvizfinance, but when I add an index = zero it says my collection is zero?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, stock

I'm trying to import stock information into an excel sheet via the finvizfinance library using Python. The dataframe correction from pandas is not correctly giving a format that could be put into excel. What is going on? Do I need to set the index to a list that is equal to all outputs of the rows from the finvizlibrary (e.g. 'Company', 'Sector', etc)? Any help would be appreciated.

When I simply print the stock_fundament I get something like the following...

{'Company': 'Tesla, Inc.', 'Sector': 'Consumer Cyclical', 'Industry': 'Auto Manufacturers', ...,'SMA20': '-11.37%', 'SMA50': '4.62%', 'SMA200': '-20.45%', 'Volume': '167,302,066', 'Change': '0.60%'}

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
Index: []

```
from finvizfinance.quote import finvizfinance
import pandas as pd
 
stock = finvizfinance('tsla')
stock_fundament = stock.ticker_fundament()
 
 
# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_fundament, index=0, columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
print(stock_fundament)
print(df)

#df = df[list(df.columns[~df.columns.duplicated()])]         
#This was used to delete potential duplicate columns

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\ncwes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pandas_simple.xlsx')
 
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
 
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.json_normalize(stock_fundament)` to read in correctly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(stock_fundament))

print(df)

       Company             Sector  ...       Volume Change
0  Tesla, Inc.  Consumer Cyclical  ...  142,799,036  5.03%
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `[]` brackets in your `index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_fundament, index=[0])
```

df gives me:

```
       Company             Sector            Industry Country         Index    P/E EPS (ttm)  ...   Price Recom   SMA20  SMA50   SMA200       Volume Change
0  Tesla, Inc.  Consumer Cyclical  Auto Manufacturers     USA  NDX, S&P 500  48.13      3.62  ...  183.26  2.40  -6.38%  9.08%  -16.38%  142,763,793  5.03%

[1 rows x 78 columns]
```

If we use the columns that you provided, you get the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_fundament, index=[0], columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])
```

df is now this:

```
     a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```